# NoReverseMatch at /add_stock Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django

Listed below are the files, I tried looking at the other answers on here but didn't seem to help. When I tried to output just the primary key by doing items.id on the add_stock.html page nothing came out so I'm wondering if there is an issue accessing the primary key for the database.

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.home,name="home"),
        path('about',views.about,name="about"),
        path('add_stock',views.add_stock,name="add_stock"),
        path('delete/<stock_id>',views.delete,name="delete")

]
```

views.py file

```
def add_stock(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = StockForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,("Stock Has Been Added"))
            return redirect('add_stock')
    else:
        stockInfo = Stock.objects.all()
        ticker = []
        for ticker_item in stockInfo:
            url = "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/market/get-quotes"
            querystring = {"region":"US","lang":"en","symbols":str(ticker_item)}

            headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-host': "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            'x-rapidapi-key': "1ab2c68079msh721b8caa3532a08p125aafjsn601191304fe3"
            }

            api_request = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

            try:
                api=json.loads(api_request.content)
                dpi=StockInfo(api['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['symbol'],api['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['regularMarketPrice'],
                api['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['fullExchangeName'],api['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['regularMarketChange'],
                api['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['regularMarketChangePercent'])
                ticker.append(dpi)
            except Exception as e:
                dpi="Error"

    return render(request,'add_stock.html',{'stockInfo':stockInfo,'ticker':ticker})

# in the add_stock html page we pass the stock_id as signature request is not passed used for completing communication
def delete(request, stock_id):
    item = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id)
    item.delete()
    return redirect(add_stock)#redirect back to the page
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Stock

class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ["ticker"]
```

Comment: If you want to access your db objects in the template you have to pass them to your context like you did with "stockInfo" here `return render(request,'add_stock.html',{'stockInfo':stockInfo...` to show the ids of all "stockInfo" objects you would have to write a template for loop like `{% for item in stockInfo%} {{item.id}} {%endfor%}`

Comment: the whole `for ticker_item in stockInfo:` loop is not the way to go. If your website ever gets bigger this would take forever. imagine how many requests you would have to make.  Cache/save the values somehow and request the infos every minute or whatever.